# Calculate Fourier coefficients in optimization problem

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization, fourier-analysis

I am using Differential Evolution optimization algorithm to estimate Fourier Coefficients to recover my objective function. In this case, coefficient samples are generated, and then the algorithm plays the role to select and improve the best answer.

However, I am quite unsure if I am computing the right way the Fourier Series by the coefficients, which are stored in the vector

veccoef = {a0, a1, b1, a2, b2,..., ncoef}

```
CalcCTCCoef[veccoef_List, ncoef_, x_List, npi_, L_] := (
  hccoef = ConstantArray[0, npi];

  For[i = 1, i <= npi, i++,
   ffour = 0.0;
   ind = 1;
   For[j = 2, j < ncoef, j++,
    ffour = ffour + veccoef[[j]]*Cos[ind*Pi*x[[i]]/a] + 
      veccoef[[j + 1]]*Sin[ind*Pi*x[[i]]/a];
    ind = ind + 1;
    j = j + 1;
    ];
   hccoef[[i]] = veccoef[[1]]/2 + ffour;
   ];
  Return[hccoef];
  )
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: `FourierCoefficient` ?

Comment: The line: ffour + veccoef[[j]]*Cos[ind*Pi*x[[i]]/a] + veccoef[[j + 1]]*Sin[ind*Pi*x[[i]]/a] does not seem to do anything since it fails to assign the calculated value to anything. Maybe you mean ffour = ffour + ...

Comment: you are right, this was a typo. Code corrected here.

Comment: Still, the question is unclear, what's the purpose of `CalcCTCCoef`? Are you trying to build your own `FourierCoefficient`? What's the meaning of `veccoef`, etc? Is `veccoef` a list of coefficient of `FourierTrigSeries` (See the Details and Options section)? Please clarify all these.

Comment: vecCoef is an arbitraty vector, which values are being iterativelly updated acc. to the optimization problem. CalcCTCCoef is the function that calculates the Fourier series by the coefficients stored in vecCoef

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to calculate a function from its Fourier coefficient. Here is a simple example with Sin:

```
n = 3;
fc = FourierCoefficient[Sin[ x], x, #] & /@ Range[-n, n];

fun[x_] = Sum[fc[[i + n + 1]] Exp[I  i x], {i, -n, n}] // Re;
Plot[{ Sin[x], fun[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
Plot[{ Sin[x] - fun[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

And here is a more complex example with a non periodic function Exp[x]:

```
n = 20;
fc = FourierCoefficient[Exp[ x], x, #] & /@ Range[-n, n];
fun[x_] = Sum[fc[[i + n + 1]] Exp[I  i x], {i, -n, n}] // Re;
Plot[{ Exp[x], fun[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
Plot[{ Exp[x] - fun[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]